# error when changing a Tkinter button command method

Tags: python, tkinter, button, canvas

**Code:**

```
from tkinter import * 

#screen 1
scr1 = Tk()
scr1.configure(bg='#2e3033')
canvas = []
teamCommentsButton = []

#update Vissuals
def updateTeams():
    for x in range(6):
        onClick = lambda : comments(x+10)
        canvas[x].itemconfig(teamCommentsButton[x], command = onClick)

def comments (team):
    print(team)
    comments = Toplevel(scr1)

for x in range(6):
    canvas.append(Canvas(scr1, width = 840, height = 326, bg='#2e3033', highlightthickness=1, highlightbackground='#2e3033'))
    teamCommentsButton.append(Button(canvas[x], text='☰', command = lambda : comments(x), width = 2, height = 1))
    teamCommentsButton[x].place(x = 20, y = 20)
    canvas[x].grid(column = 0 if x < 3 else 1, row = (x if x < 3 else x - 3))

scr1.title('Pit TV - Match')
updateTeams()
scr1.mainloop()
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Documents\Team 1710\Code\GKC2022\test.py", line 26, in <module>
    updateTeams()
  File "c:\Users\user\Documents\Team 1710\Code\GKC2022\test.py", line 13, in updateTeams
    canvas[x].itemconfig(teamCommentsButton[x], command = onClick)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2903, in itemconfigure
    return self._configure(('itemconfigure', tagOrId), cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1636, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid boolean operator in tag search expression
```

I want to be able to change the parameter of a command in a Tkinter button but I get this error when I try to do it. I have tried changing the parameter to a constant `onClick = lambda : comments(10)` and I have tried directly putting the method call as the command `command = comments(x+10)` but both give me the same error

on top of that when I remove the call to `updateTeams()` the code runs without errors but prints 5 no matter which button I click. I would expect that it prints a range from 0-5 depending on the button I click because the parameter I set for each button is dependent on x.

here is what the window looks like when I remove `updateTeams()` [window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Kuji.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems in your Code:

#### Problem 1

The buttons are not items of the canvases.

You have to treat the button like a regular tkinter widget and use configure:

```py
teamCommentsButton[x].configure(command=onClick)
```

If you want the button to actually be inside the canvas you have to add it to another frame and add that frame as an item to the window using:

```py
canvas[x].create_window((20, 20), window=buttonFrame)
```

#### Problem 2

In Python lambda functions created in loops will execute the same function. That means your lambdas in updateTeams() will always use x = 15. This can be avoided by using an own function for creating lambdas:

```py
def create_lambda(x):
    return lambda: comments(x + 10)
```

Comment: Feels extremely overcomplicated but it works so I cant complain. Thanks